# Combine 2 arrays of different length

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have an array with 100 values(array1). I have another array with 8 values(array2). I want to take the values from array2 and use them as keys and extract the values in array1 for those keys.

The array_combine function won't work as they are of different lengths.

I have tried

```
function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
    $count = min(count($arr1), count($arr2));
    return array_combine(array_slice($arr1, 0, $count), array_slice($arr2, 0, $count));
}
```

But this doesn't work.....this gives me an array with the correct keys, but the values are incorrect, I think because it is slicing array1.

Could someone give some assistance. There is a fair amount of literature on this already, I know, but they all give solutions very similar to the one above which isn't working.

Many thanks for the time you have taken.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Because I think you're using the word "value" to mean two different things depending on context, and it's confusing. Sometimes you seem to mean "value" as in a key-value pair, while other times you're calling the whole key-value pair a "value". Please reword your question using the terms, "key", "value" and "entry" (a.k.a. key-value pair), discerningly, _e.g._ "I have an array with 100 _entries_..."

Comment: Thank Eric, You are correct, I am a bit loose with my language. the arrays are too long to give you, however, both arrays contain key-value pairs. Array2 has 8 eight key-value pairs and array1 has 100. I am only interested in taking the values in array2 and and finding the values in array1 for the keys, indicated by the values in array2.

Answer (score 1):

something like this one:

```
function combine($array1, $array2) {
    $array3 = array();
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) { //loop through all entries of array2

        //get the entry of array1 that corresponds to the value of array2's entry
        if (isset($array1[$value]) {
            $array3[$key] = $array1[$value] 
        }
    }

    return $array3;
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should give you something for thought.

Comment: And check whether `$value` key exists in `$array1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. loop the 2nd array and extract the value from array1 with using value of array2 as index for array1

```
foreach ( $array2 as $arr2 ){
   $temp[]= $array[ $arr2 ];
}
return $temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code

```
function array_combine2($arr1, $arr2) {
    foreach($arr2 as $val){
     $arr3[] = $arr1[$val];
     }

    return $arr3;
}
```

For inctanse,

```
    $arr1['x'] = 2;
$arr1['y'] = 3;
$arr1['z'] = 4;

$arr2[0] = 'x';
$arr2[1] = 'y';
$arr2[2] = 'z';
```

the above function will return the below as resbonse

```
$arr3[0] = 2;
$arr3[1] = 3;
$arr3[2] = 4;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. In fact none of these suggestions have worked.

Comment: To give a bit more detail, array1 is a key-value pair. The value in this is a score given by a doctor on an image, which is the key. The second array is also a set of key-value pairs but a much smaller array (always smaller) - the key is the image number and the value is a score for that image, but by a different doctor. Basically I am trying to pull all the scores by doctor 1 for the small set of images scored by doctor 2.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `array_slice()` will disregard any association between the arrays based on keys/indexes.  `array_slice()` operates using `offset` values; this is why it is the wrong tool for the job.

`array_intersect_key()` is a suitable call to filter an array using another array's keys.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00d3461035ff597608401f1cd2441ec967bfa663))

```
for($char='A',$score=100; $score>0; ++$char,--$score){
    $dr_img_scores1["IMG_$char"]=$score;    // generate 100 unique elements
}
//var_export($dr_img_scores1);  // uncomment to see what this looks like

// eight arbitrary elements to use as extraction keys on $array1
$dr_img_scores2=['IMG_CL'=>13,'IMG_Z'=>44,'IMG_BP'=>82,'IMG_L'=>50,
                 'IMG_CD'=>2,'IMG_X'=>91,'IMG_BM'=>7,'IMG_AV'=>0];    

var_export(array_intersect_key($dr_img_scores1,$dr_img_scores2));
// notice that $dr_img_scores1's element order is preserved
```

Output:

```
array (
  'IMG_L' => 89,
  'IMG_X' => 77,
  'IMG_Z' => 75,
  'IMG_AV' => 53,
  'IMG_BM' => 36,
  'IMG_BP' => 33,
  'IMG_CD' => 19,
  'IMG_CL' => 11,
)
```

Note: If `$dr_img_scores1` or `$dr_img_scores2` are not in order, you can use `ksort()` on them to synchronize their orders to permit an easy visual comparison of scores.

Comment: @GhostRider I inappropriately used this page as a duplicate link yesterday.  Because your question was a little bit unclear, I mistook the task that you required.  If this is what you are looking for, please award the green tick and perhaps update your question to improve clarity.  If my answer does not yield the correct result, please take a moment to explain what isn't right.  Thank you.